# How can I get the coordinates of my component that is outside of the viewport in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: Yeah dont answer my question that works too!

I placed getBoundingClientRect() in both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate and they both return the same values.
When I use getBoundingClientRect it returns a random value like 330 which is completely way off because it's less than than the window viewport size.

Chrome's getBoundingClientRect:
ClientRect
bottom
:
346.4270935058594
height
:
0
left
:
0
right
:
394
top
:
346.4270935058594
width
:
394

Also, side note: When I use this function in Microsoft Edge the values like height and top are more accurate

Microsoft Edge:
{bottom: 1150.919921875, height: 513.05993652...", left: 0, right: 390, top: 637.85998535...", width: 390}

```
class Hoop extends React.Component {
state = {
    rect: {},
    offsetY: 0
}

componentDidMount() {

    const { documentElement, body } = document;

    //remember: window.innerHeight and window.pageYOffset are in the global
    //scope as innerHeight and pageYOffset anyway, because window is the global object.

    const scrollTop = pageYOffset || documentElement.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;

    const rect = ReactDOM
        .findDOMNode(this.targetHoopRef)
        .getBoundingClientRect();


    // const offsetY = rect.top + scrollTop + pageYOffset;
    const offsetY = 0;
    this.setState({ rect, offsetY });

}

componentDidUpdate() {
    const rect = ReactDOM
        .findDOMNode(this.targetHoopRef)
        .getBoundingClientRect();

    // console.log(rect);
}



render() {
    const { projectname, projectdate, projecttools, projectdescript, droptargetname } = this.props;
    const { rect, offsetY } = this.state;
    return (
            <Card className="column" id="hoop" ref="test">
                <TargetHoop isOver=""
                            projectname={projectname}
                            droptargetname={droptargetname}
                            cardRect={rect}
                            offsetY={offsetY}
                            ref={ref => this.targetHoopRef = ref} />
               <extrastuff/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to produce a minimal code example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Ouroborus added minimal code